# Conditional Weather Probability

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics

Given that the weather forecast is 40% chance of rain each of the next 3 days. What are the odds it will rain within the next 3 days?

Comment: **Hint**: It is the same as 1- probability that it will not rain the next three days.

Comment: Is daily weather independent of other days, or does your location have a wet season?

Comment: How is this conditional? If each day has a $40\%$ chance of rain, shouldn't they all be independent?

Comment: Well you could have rain on all 3 days...you could have rain on just day 1 just day 2 or just day 3...you could have no rain on all 3 days. ect..What are the odds Within the next 3 days given each day being 40%

Comment: I solved this with the Bernoulli process. (Real curious if it could be solved with conditional probability though) Anyways just looking for answers, please post them below and ill choose the best one.

Comment: @JeffFromFuture Change the title since this is not conditional probability problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $NR_{i}=$The Event of not raining in $i^{th}$ day.
So we have to calculate $P[$Raining within next 3 days$]$=$1-P[$Not Raining in any of next 3 days$]$=$1-P[NR_{1},NR_{2},NR_{3}]=1-P[NR_{1}]P[NR_{2}]P[NR_{3}]=1-(1-\frac{40}{100})^{3}=1-(\frac{3}{5})^{3}=\frac{98}{125}$

The above was done assuming independence of occurence of rain in consecutive days

Comment: yeah thats what i got. 78% goodjob!